# Logical Exclusive OR's vs Conditional Logical OR's Within An For Loop

Tags: c#, loops, conditional-statements, logical-operators

Recently I have been working on a project that requires a loop to run x amount of times. Simply wanted to exclude certain output `x` values.

*Bellow is an example of what I THOUGH would work:*

```
// Create a 1-58 Loop
for (int n = 1; n < 59; n++)
{
    // Exclude Values
    if (n != 2 || n != 11 || n != 16 || n != 40)
    {
        // Display Data
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

The operation `n != 2 || n != 11 || n != 16 || n != 40` Under any normal situations would exclude the values that do not equal `!=` value `x`. However this does not work and still renders all values and ignores the operation once a or statement `||` is introduced.

*Bellow is a solution I found after playing around for a bit:*

```
// Create a 1-58 Loop
for (int n = 1; n < 59; n++)
{
    // Exclude Values
    if (n == 2 ^ n == 11 ^ n != 16 ^ n == 40)
    {
        // Display Data
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

So my question is why does the Logical exclusive `||` not work in a for loop but a Conditional logical `^` does? I'm pulling my information from [this wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#:%7E:text=Conditional%20logical%20OR%20operator%20%7C%7C,-The%20conditional%20logical&text=The%20result%20of%20x%20%7C%7C,true%20%2C%20y%20is%20not%20evaluated.&text=The%20logical%20OR%20operator%20%7C%20also,but%20always%20evaluates%20both%20operands.). If i'm wrong about something please have no hesitations to correct me!

Comment: `^` is the [logical *exclusive* OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-), while `||` is the [conditional logical OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-). Exclusive OR is different than OR, the main difference being that exclusive OR requires that one AND ONLY ONE of the conditions evaluates to `true`, whereas a conditional OR will also return `true` if both conditions evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` is the [logical *exclusive* OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-), while `||` is the [conditional logical OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-). Exclusive OR is different than OR in that exclusive OR requires that **one AND ONLY ONE** of the conditions evaluates to `true`, whereas a conditional OR will also return `true` if **both** conditions evaluate to `true`.

Also note that the conditional OR (`||`) will return as soon as any condition evaluates to `true` (evaluated from left to right); no other conditions are evaluated since they would have no affect on the outcome (this makes it different than the `|` operator, where all conditions are evaluated).

Let's take a look at the statement that works:

```
if (n == 2 ^ n == 11 ^ n != 16 ^ n == 40)
```

If we break this down for one of the values we want to exclude, say `2` for example, we have:

```
if (true ^ false ^ true ^ false) =>
       \   /      /       /
        \ /      /       /
if (   true ^ true ^ false     ) =>
          \   /       /
           \ /       /
if (      false ^ false        ) =>
              \   / 
               \ /
if (          false            )
```

Then let's look at the condition that *doesn't* work and now we see why:

```
if (n != 2 || n != 11 || n != 16 || n != 40)
```

For the number `2`, this becomes:

```
if (false || true || true || true)
         \   / 
          \ /
if (     true                    )     // evaluation stops at the first `true` result
```

---

So what else can we do in this situation? Well, we can swap the `||` operator with the `&&` operator (which is the [conditional logical AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) operator), which only returns `true` if **both** conditions evaluate to `true` (and it also short circuits if any condition returns `false`, since no further evaluations are necessary).

Let's take a look:

```
if (n != 2 && n != 11 && n != 16 && n != 40)
```

For the number `2`, this becomes:

```
if (false && true && true && true)
         \   / 
          \ /
if (     false                   )     // evaluation stops at the first `false` result
```

Comment: Appreciate the time and effort to explain this! This is exactly the explanation I was looking for! I will be using this as future reference!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n != 2 || n != 11 || n != 16 || n != 40)
```

This will be true on a 2. Because a 2 is not 11.

If you want to exclude those. You should do:

```
if (n != 2 && n != 11 && n != 16 && n != 40)
```

Comment: This works but I'm still in question. Is `n` already defined as values 1-58? For each new time it's n++ the value of n was still the number previously. Why does the if statement need to look if `n=2` AND `n=11` at the same time? Would that not return false as `n` no longer equals 2 or the number previously?

Comment: Assume n = 2.
if (n != 2 (false) || n != 11 (true) || n != 16 || n != 40)
Thats how c# works. It will look on the entire statement every time. You could use a list.
List<int> excludedNumbers = new List<int>{2, 11, 16, 40}
Then the condition could be if(!excludedNumbers.Contains(n))
The (!) will invert the statement.

Comment: Thinking of these statements as true/false's has helped me allot. Thanks for the advice and wisdom.